# Mapbox.js returns tiles in wrong order

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox

When using Mapbox-gl.js in the latest chrome browser, everything works fine. 
When I want to use the default mapbox.js implementation, the map tiles are getting al mixed up and shown totally wrong. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrdO7.jpg)

[image: Imgur]

I have totally no idea why this does not work with mapbox.js, while I did not experience any problem with mapbox-gl.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're loading the CSS files for the mapbox.js library. Tiles being arranged that way are usually a symptom of missing CSS rules.

Comment: You're totally right. I forgot to link the proper css for the regular mapbox.js